# Apache POI XSSF Loading issue

Tags: java, apache-poi, xlsx

We are trying to read an xlsx file using apache POI. Every thing works fine. But sometimes when we upload a xlsx file, it gives below error.

```
java.io.IOException: Unable to parse xml bean
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLTypeLoader.parse(POIXMLTypeLoader.java:118)
    at org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.WorkbookDocument$Factory.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.onDocumentRead(XSSFWorkbook.java:347)
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.load(POIXMLDocument.java:190)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:290)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:720)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:280)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655)
    at io.vertx.core.eventbus.impl.HandlerRegistration.deliver(HandlerRegistration.java:213)
    at io.vertx.core.eventbus.impl.HandlerRegistration.handle(HandlerRegistration.java:192)
    at io.vertx.core.eventbus.impl.EventBusImpl.lambda$deliverToHandler$3(EventBusImpl.java:503)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.lambda$wrapTask$3(ContextImpl.java:359)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The prefix "x15" for element "x15:workbookPr" is not bound.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.poi.util.DocumentHelper.readDocument(DocumentHelper.java:137)
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLTypeLoader.parse(POIXMLTypeLoader.java:115)
    ... 25 common frames omitted
```

If we copy the same content to another xlsx file and upload it, everything works fine. We are unable to identify the root cause of this error. Appreciate any help / suggestions.

Jars Used : 
poi-3.16.jar
poi-ooxml-3.16.jar
poi-ooxml-schemas-3.16.jar

Update :

Even with poi version 3.14 we are getting below exception:

```
org.apache.poi.POIXMLException: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: error: Use of undefined namespace prefix: x15
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.onDocumentRead(XSSFWorkbook.java:402)
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.load(POIXMLDocument.java:178)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:249)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:302)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:720)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:280)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655)
    at io.vertx.core.eventbus.impl.HandlerRegistration.deliver(HandlerRegistration.java:213)
    at io.vertx.core.eventbus.impl.HandlerRegistration.handle(HandlerRegistration.java:192)
    at io.vertx.core.eventbus.impl.EventBusImpl.lambda$deliverToHandler$3(EventBusImpl.java:503)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.lambda$wrapTask$3(ContextImpl.java:359)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: error: Use of undefined namespace prefix: x15
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale$SaxLoader.load(Locale.java:3499)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.parseToXmlObject(Locale.java:1277)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.parseToXmlObject(Locale.java:1264)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeLoaderBase.parse(SchemaTypeLoaderBase.java:345)
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLTypeLoader.parse(POIXMLTypeLoader.java:92)
    at org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.WorkbookDocument$Factory.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.onDocumentRead(XSSFWorkbook.java:336)
    ... 24 common frames omitted
```

Code Initialising the Read of xlsx. This where we are getting this exception:

```
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
```

Comment: you can try this `Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(file);`

Comment: That also gives the same exception.

Comment: Where did this file come from? If you open the file in Excel and do a Save-As, does the problem go away?

Comment: Hi @Manjunath, did you ever find the solution or the root cause of the problem ? Facing exactly same problem

Answer (score 0):

Specifically about this problem  not about Apache poi jar file version 3.16 or 3.14 you mention this  java.io.IOException: Unable to parse xml bean and org.apache.poi.POIXMLException this looks problem with your code.

Comment: I dont think its related to code. If I understand it right, one of the poi related xml schema file is throwing this exception. Need to get the reason behind why its failing for specific xlsx file.

Comment: Ok Then you think it is related to poi xml schema file then Report  bug in Apache poi https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/enter_bug.cgi or please search there doc you will get proper solution.